# Oracle Apex Change IG column which is select list to use html expression

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive grid in application.

One of the columns is a select list but i need to implement mouse hover on that column also.
The column uses select list query:

```
select name as d, id as r from kpi;
```

The select query for grid is:

```
select kpi_name, kpi_value from data_kpi where dept = :DEPT;
```

Here KPI_NAME is the column using the select list query.

Now i need to add mouse hover on this kpi_name column and for that i need to change its attribute to html expression from select list  and add the span tags:

`<span title="My tooltip text">#COLUMN_NAME#</span>`

Can i incorporate select list query in the main grid query itself ?

Apex: 20.2

Comment: "Can i ...?" - why wouldn't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: I am unable to frame the query which is why i need help.

Comment: Aha. OK; I posted how it should look like. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Query itself would contain almost everything you wrote, concatenating "parts" of it into a final form. Something like this:

```
select '<span title="My tooltip text">' || e.employee_name || '</span>' as emp_name
from employees e
```